# OpenLiberty features repository-resolver install-map

Tags: maven, open-liberty

I am getting below error for both install-map and repository-resolver. Could you please provide any pointers to resolve this.

```
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata io.openliberty.features:install-map/maven-metadata.xml in local 
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for io.openliberty.features:install-map/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Could not find override bundle io.openliberty.features:install-map for the current Open Liberty version 21.0.0.5
io.openliberty.tools.common.plugins.util.PluginExecutionException: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Could not get the highest version from the range: [21.0.0.5, 21.0.0.6)
    at io.openliberty.tools.maven.InstallFeatureSupport$InstallFeatureMojoUtil.downloadArtifact(InstallFeatureSupport.java:86)
    at io.openliberty.tools.common.plugins.util.InstallFeatureUtil.downloadOverrideJar(InstallFeatureUtil.java:622)
    at io.openliberty.tools.common.plugins.util.InstallFeatureUtil.loadInstallJarFile(InstallFeatureUtil.java:108)
    at io.openliberty.tools.common.plugins.util.InstallFeatureUtil.<init>(InstallFeatureUtil.java:91)
    at io.openliberty.tools.maven.InstallFeatureSupport$InstallFeatureMojoUtil.<init>(InstallFeatureSupport.java:48)
    at io.openliberty.tools.maven.InstallFeatureSupport.getInstallFeatureUtil(InstallFeatureSupport.java:165)
    at io.openliberty.tools.maven.server.InstallFeatureMojo.installFeatures(InstallFeatureMojo.java:56)
    at io.openliberty.tools.maven.server.InstallFeatureMojo.doExecute(InstallFeatureMojo.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.pluginsupport.MojoSupport.execute(MojoSupport.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.twdata.maven.mojoexecutor.MojoExecutor.executeMojo(MojoExecutor.java:119)
    at io.openliberty.tools.maven.server.StartDebugMojoSupport.runLibertyMojo(StartDebugMojoSupport.java:227)
    at io.openliberty.tools.maven.server.StartDebugMojoSupport.runLibertyMojoInstallFeature(StartDebugMojoSupport.java:221)
    at io.openliberty.tools.maven.server.DevMojo.doExecute(DevMojo.java:705)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.pluginsupport.MojoSupport.execute(MojoSupport.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Could not get the highest version from the range: [21.0.0.5, 21.0.0.6)
    at io.openliberty.tools.maven.AbstractLibertySupport.createArtifact(AbstractLibertySupport.java:234)
    at io.openliberty.tools.maven.AbstractLibertySupport.getArtifact(AbstractLibertySupport.java:158)
    at io.openliberty.tools.maven.AbstractLibertySupport.getArtifact(AbstractLibertySupport.java:209)
    at io.openliberty.tools.maven.InstallFeatureSupport$InstallFeatureMojoUtil.downloadArtifact(InstallFeatureSupport.java:84)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.VersionRangeResolutionException: Unable to resolve version range fram io.openliberty.features:install-map:jar:[21.0.0.5, 21.0.0.6)
    at io.openliberty.tools.maven.AbstractLibertySupport.resolveVersionRange(AbstractLibertySupport.java:335)
    at io.openliberty.tools.maven.AbstractLibertySupport.createArtifact(AbstractLibertySupport.java:232)
    ... 39 more
[DEBUG] io.openliberty.features:features:21.0.0.5 is resolved from project repositories.
```

At the end I am getting the below error

```
Failed to execute goal io.openliberty.tools:liberty-maven-plugin:3.2.4:dev (default-cli) on project wagematchservices: An invocation of the springBootUtility command failed. The command is not available on the targeted Liberty runtime. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal io.openliberty.tools:liberty-maven-plugin:3.2.4:dev (default-cli) on project wagematchservices: An invocation of the springBootUtility command
```

Below is my pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath />
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
  <groupId></groupId>
  <artifactId></artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name></name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>io.openliberty.features</groupId>
    <artifactId>install-map</artifactId>
    <version>18.0.0.2</version>
</dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.13.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>19.6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.openliberty.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>liberty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <appsDirectory>apps</appsDirectory>
                    <installAppPackages>spring-boot-project</installAppPackages>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: If you remove the install-map dependency from your maven pom does it work?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added this dependency in pom and manually downloaded install-map Jar into local mvn repo to see if this resolves the issue. It did not help. Initially when I did not have this entry in pom I was getting the same error.

Comment: Can you share your server.xml?

Comment: Could you please share the features in your server.xml? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The install-map and repository-resolver debug messages can be safely ignored and there is no need to include the install-map dependency in pom.xml.  Those artifacts are only needed if using an old version of Open Liberty (specifically, 18.0.0.2).  The following issue will address removing/improving those messages: https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.maven/issues/1142

To use Liberty dev mode with a Spring Boot application, see the steps provided in https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.maven/issues/1143#issuecomment-845241015 which will be added to the documentation.

Comment: Eric, Thanks for your time. I will try this and update soon. I was working on a very similar project and I was using Jar packaging and it worked fine. But I want to see if changing to War packaging resolves this issue this time. Will update soon.

Comment: Eric, I was reading your above answer today again. My application is a web service. As I mentioned, I was able to start a very similar application in dev mode earlier with Jar packaging. This issue occurs even in the regular liberty run mode. In the end after error about install-map and repository-resolver dependencies, I get "BUILD FAILURE. ...An invocation of the springBootUtility command failed. ...The command is not available on the targeted Liberty runtime". I would prefer not changing the packaging type unless I have to, for a solid reason. Please advice.

Comment: Could you add an additional configuration for open-liberty inside the `<configuration>` tag and check again?


```<configuration>
      <assemblyArtifact>
  <groupId>io.openliberty</groupId>
         <artifactId>openliberty-runtime</artifactId>
         <version>21.0.0.5</version>
  <type>zip</type>
 </assemblyArtifact>
</configuration>```

Comment: The above configuration doesn't require you to make changes which Eric suggested. Thanks!